# Module config page linked on Management Toolbar

Tags: routes

I created a config page for my new module.  Whenever I enable the module, a link to the config page is added to the Management menu across the top of the screen as well as a configure link next to the module name in the Modules page.  How do I configure this page so that it just shows up with the configure link on the modules page and not in the menu.  Below is the code from hook_menu:

```
$items['admin/mymodule/settings'] = array(
  'title' => 'mymodule Module Configuration',
  'description' => 'Settings for my module',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('_mymodule_admin'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule settings'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,   
);
```

The module has a function called _mymodule_admin that returns a form array.  The config page works great. I just want to prevent the link from appearing on the management menu when the module is activated on my production site.

My info file contains the following line

```
configure = 'admin/timesdb/settings'
```

And my form callback has includes this line

```
return system_settings_form($form);
```

With the relevant form elements assigned above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have added a MENU_NORMAL_ITEM under the admin menu, so it will automatically put it in the admin toolbar (that is also the default so if you exclude that parameter it will also be a menu normal item).

If you change it to MENU_CALLBACK, that will create the link between that url and your page callback, but it will not create an item in the menu.

See [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for all the menu item types.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  I'll award the bounty as soon as the site allows me to (about 13 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Its a piece of code put it in the .info file Like :

```
configure = admin/structure/block
```

Take a look at BLOCK module or other contributed modules and see the HOOK_MENU in the .module file.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I already have that there.